# Update array item in the reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

In my reducer state I have array

```
grounds: [
   {
     name: 'name1',
     id: 123
   }
   {
     name: 'name2',
     id: 456
   }
   {
     name: 'name3',
     id: 789
   }

]
```

I am dispatching an action that looks like this

```
export const renameGound = (newName, id) => {
    return{
        type: RENAME_GROUND,
        newName: newName,
        id: id
    }
}
```

What I want is to update name value to object that has the id that i get as an action.id. This is what I have tried and it does not work.

```
case actionTypes.RENAME_GROUND:
            return{
                ...state,
                grounds: state.grounds.forEach(el => {
                    if(el.id === action.id){
                        el.name = action.newName
                    }
                })
            }
```

I have mistakenly instead of a grounds in the case above putted loader, and it works, I do not know how but it works. But when i try it like this it doesnt....

How can I update the right object correct way?

Comment: You can omit the second parameter if key and value are the same: newName: newName is the same as newName,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you try the next code in the reducer?

```
return {
        ...state,
        grounds: state.grounds.map(el => {
          if (el.id === action.id) {
            return {
              ...el,
              name: action.newName
            };
          }

          return el;
        })
      };
```

It's very important that the reducer stays pure. You should never mutate its arguments inside.

More information could be found in the Redux [documentation](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the reduce syntax like this:

```
 return{
            ...state,
            grounds: state.groundgrounds.reduce((newGrounds, ground) => {
                if(ground.id === action.id) {
                    newGrounds.push({
                        ...ground,
                        name: action.name
                    })
                 } else {
                        newGrounds.push(ground)
                 }
                return newGrounds;
             }, [])
        }
```